# Eclipse Console error (chinese output) how to fix?

Tags: eclipse, console

[image]

I am geting this text type that i dont understund...i made reset setings and the same hapens...any advice??

Comment: It is trying to set screen colours using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) but the Eclipse console does not support them.

Comment: Ok i fixed by installing this .... https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=1592292